# emacs not recognizing C- prefix for '

Tags: emacs, remote-access, key-bindings

I'm trying to learn to use shell-switcher in
emacs (https://github.com/DamienCassou/shell-switcher).  On my
local machine it works exactly as described.  On a remote machine
that I access through ssh emacs seems to ignore the `C-` prefix in the
shell-switcher default keybinding of `C-'`.

On my local machine, `C-h k C-'` yields:

```
C-' runs the command shell-switcher-switch-buffer, which is an
interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
`shell-switcher.el'.
```

But on the remote machine it yields:

```
' runs the command self-insert-command, which is an interactive
built-in function in `C source code'.

It is bound to many ordinary text characters.
```

Other `C-` bindings work as expected.

Could anyone suggest how I might further debug this to figure out
where along the [local shell--ssh--remote shell--remote emacs] chain my `C-` is getting intercepted?

Comment: On your local machine are you using emacs in a terminal or are you using the GUI?

Comment: Note that your local emacs can edit remotely over ssh using [TRAMP](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode).

Comment: @molbdnilo, thanks - I'd actually stopped using the TRAMP workflow a few years ago because I find it useful to use remote git and python and R interpreters through the remote emacs, and TRAMP seemed to introduce layers of complexity to that...  Maybe I should give TRAMP another look.

Comment: @RandyMorris, thanks - I'm in the GUI on the local machine, largely because I use PDFview mode to read journal articles.  Not sure how I managed to not think of that, but firing up emacs in the local terminal behaves the same way as the remote.  So it seems like my terminal emulator (iterm2 on OS x) is the culprit...  I'll dig into that deeper.  Thanks a bunch!